# Error when setting Piwik analytics

Tags: godaddy, tracking, matomo

I've uploaded the latest version of Piwik unto my web server, which is hosted by go daddy.com, on a linux hosting plan.
I'm setting it up (accessing it from my browser as instructed) and I have the "Piwik>installation" page open on step 3 (database set-up ) of 9.
I don't know what to imput in the field "database server"... the default is the number 127.0.0.1

When I leave that input as is, and click "Next" leaving the gives the error:

> "Error when trying to connect to database server: SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 111"

and changing that input to "localhost" gives me another error:

> "Error when trying to connect to database server:SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy doesn't allow localhost as a db server:
[What server should I use in my code to connect to my database?](http://help.godaddy.com/article/197) in the Help Center.

Also [Setting up a MySQL or SQL Server Database for Your Hosting Account](http://help.godaddy.com/article/36)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did. Obviously, your host won't let piwik install database. You have to set it yourself. For that, you have to choose the following:

1. MySQL Database/User Name
2. Password
3. read Only User Name (not needed here)

Now, going back to Piwik installation page, enter the following:

- **Database server**: put in your database's host name, you should find it in the database information section of your hosting provider. Should be like:  databasename.db.0000000.hostedressource.com
- **Login**: put your User Name chosen in 1.
- **password:** put your password chosen in 2.
- **database Name:** same as MySQL Database/User Name chosen in 1.

Hope that helps someone. If you have any trouble with setting up a database on your own, your hosting provider will help.